# Error when Creating B2C User Attributes/Extension Attributes/Custom Claims

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, user-permissions, azureportal, claims

I'm trying to create, delete, or modify B2C extension attributes in the User Attributes tab under Azure AD B2C resource, because some of our existing ones are misnamed. But, whenever I try to add a User Attribute, I get the following error every time I try to save it:

> Create user attribute
> Could not save user attribute: There is a problem with the service. If you created this B2C directory just now, please try again after couple of minutes. If the problem persists, please contact Support (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-support/).
> If you do not have a B2C directory you can refer https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-get-started/

Initially, I thought this was a permissions issue, but now I'm starting to think that it's some sort of an error with my account or something. I spent a lot of time researching permissions, but I haven't been able to find anything clear about this particular action, at least without searching for the roles themselves. My boss is a Global Administrator and has no problem creating or modifying them as far as I can tell. I initially asked him to give me the "Attribute Definition Admin" and "Attribute Assignment Admin" roles, but I later realized that was wrong, since those are tied to the "custom security attributes", which are different. However, I later asked him to give me the "External ID User Flow Attribute Administrator" role instead, which I'm nearly certain is correct, going off of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#external-id-user-flow-attribute-administrator), but it still gives me the same error.

Any idea why this may be happening? I haven't really been able to find any documentation about the roles that could grant me this permission, save for Graph API permissions, but I'd prefer to do it through the Azure Portal, if possible. Am I overlooking something, or is this an Azure bug?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody trying to figure this out, it actually let me create an attribute, I guess I just didn't test that aspect specifically (I do think I needed the role though). I think the reason I couldn't delete a specific attribute is because it wasn't set to null for all users, at least going off of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-user-flow#remove-extension-attribute) article, as it let me delete a blank "test" attribute just fine.

I do wish it had a more descriptive error message though...